# Change background image using drop-down list?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a quick question I am currently developing a website with a chat system and I want the background image of the website to change when the user selects the specific chat room from the drop-down box

Below is the current setup of the dropdown select's

```
<div class="container chat-signin">
    <form class="form-signin">
        <h2>Chat Login</h2>
        <label for="nickname">Nickname</label> <input type="text" placeholder="Nickname" id="nickname">
        <div>
            <label for="chatroom">Chatroom</label> <select size="1" id="chatroom">
                                    <option>Gaming Soc</option>
                                    <option>Pokemon Soc</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" id="enterRoom">Sign in</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

I was thinking that it could be done using jQuery but I am at a loss when it comes to implementing it

Here's a an example of when I am trying to do

If the user selects Gaming Soc is changes to background 1 if they select Pookemon Soc is changes to background 2

Any help would great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this [**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/ca0jqga2/), you pick the value of the `option` and pick the corresponding `background-image` from an array

```js
var bgArray = [
  '//placehold.it/400x300?text=BG1',
  '//placehold.it/400x300?text=BG2'
]
$('#chatroom').on('change', function() {
  value = $(this).val() - 1;
  $('#bgDiv').css({
    'background-image': 'url(' + bgArray[value] + ')'
  });
});
```

```css
#bgDiv {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  outline: 1px dotted gray;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container chat-signin">
  <form class="form-signin">
    <h2>Chat Login</h2>

    <label for="nickname">Nickname</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Nickname" id="nickname">
    <div>
      <label for="chatroom">Chatroom</label>
      <select size="1" id="chatroom">
        <option value="1">Gaming Soc</option>
        <option value="2">Pokemon Soc</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" id="enterRoom">Sign in</button>
  </form>
</div>

<!-- for demo only -->
<hr>
<div id="bgDiv"></div>
```

Comment: Hey Man Thanks alot great example, just one thing the images I want to use are in the same folder as the html can I just call them //image1.jpg, //image2.jpg ?

Comment: You welcome, I'm glad it helped, the two forward slashes`//` represents non-relative url because in the example I was grabbing the images from some website, doing it this way can include both cases if the website `http://example.com` and `https://example.com`, but in your case don't put any forward slashes just write the image names `image1.jpg` and `image2.jpg` since they are in the same folder level with your webpage

Answer (score 1):

Javascript

```
var bgChange = function() {
    var bgVal = $("#chatroom").val(), chatRoom = $("#chatRoom"); // chatRoom (chatRoom is object id)
    if( bgVal == "1" ) {
        chatRoom.css("background-image", "url(1.jpg)");      
    } else if( bgVal == "2" ){
        chatRoom.css("background-image", "url(2.jpg)");      
    }
};
```

HTML

```
<select onchange="bgChange()" size="1" id="chatroom">
    <option value="1">Gaming Soc</option>
    <option value="2">Pokemon Soc</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try utilizing multiple `background-image` properties at `css` to request each image once , setting initial `background-size` to `0 0, 0 0` . If `select` `option` `selectedIndex` is `0` set `background-size` to `100vw 100vh, 00` , if `selectedIndex` is `1` set `background-size` to `0 0, 100vw 100vh`.

```js
var arr = ["100vw 100vh, 0 0", "0 0, 100vw 100vh"];
$("#chatroom").change(function(e) {
  $("body").css("backgroundSize", arr[this.selectedIndex])
})
```

```css
body {
  background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/400/300/technics)
    , url(http://lorempixel.com/400/300/cats);
  background-size: 0, 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="container chat-signin">
  <form class="form-signin">
    <h2>Chat Login</h2>
    <label for="nickname">Nickname</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Nickname" id="nickname">
    <div>
      <label for="chatroom">Chatroom</label>
      <select size="1" id="chatroom">
        <option>Gaming Soc</option>
        <option>Pokemon Soc</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" id="enterRoom">Sign in</button>
  </form>
</div>
```